# Angular Failed to load template from templatecache useless error

Tags: angularjs

Trying to start a new project with the fancy es6/module stuff. I'm using gulp, ngAnnotate, browserify, angular-templatecache, etc... Anyway, I'm trying to actually run my base setup and its

```
Error: [$compile:tpload] Failed to load template: components/unauthenticated-container/unauthenticated-container.component.html (HTTP status: undefined undefined)
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.1/$compile/tpload?p0=components%2Funauthent…ainer%2Funauthenticated-container.component.html&p1=undefined&p2=undefined
    at angular.js:68
    at l (angular.js:19730)
    at s (angular.js:16648)
    at angular.js:16692
    at d.$eval (angular.js:17972)
    at d.$digest (angular.js:17786)
    at d.$apply (angular.js:18080)
    at angular.js:1841
    at Object.a [as invoke] (angular.js:4842)
    at a (angular.js:1839)
```

What I can't understand is if I put a breakpoint in the `$templateRequest`, the `$templateCache` contains the template I'm trying to get. I can do

```
$templateCache.get('components/unauthenticated-container/unauthenticated-container.component.html');
```

and get the template I'm expecting. I'm not sure what the `(HTTP status: undefined undefined)` from the error above really means. The generated file to populate the templateCache looks correct to me:

```
angular.module("templates", []).run(["$templateCache", function($templateCache) {$templateCache.put("components/authenticated-container/authenticated-container.component.html","<div>Authenticated</div>\n");
$templateCache.put("components/unauthenticated-container/unauthenticated-container.component.html","<div>\n  <div ui-view></div>\n</div>\n");}]);
```

Is there anything obvious I'm missing or anything I can try?

Answer (score 4):

Turns out I had an error in one of my interceptors and the $http wasn't surfacing the error.

Comment: The error in my case was due to $injector not being able to resolve a dependency